# Исключение категории при выборке из базы данных wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Есть код, с помощью которого выбираются все уникальные значения мета-поля "driver".

```
$drivers_all = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'driver');
```

Подскажите как добавить значение, чтоб исключить из выборки определённую категорию?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
$drivers_all = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'driver' AND meta_key!='no_driver'");
```

Comment: Мне надо исключить одну из категорий в процессе выборке, типа "cat=-20".

Comment: напишите тогда вместо `meta_key!='no_driver'` `cat!=20`. Я же не знаю названия ваших полей

Comment: Мне не надо исключить значение одного из мета-полей, мне надо из выборки исключить КАТЕГОРИЮ (рубрику)

Comment: На ваш взгляд номер нужной к исключению категории хранится иначе?

Comment: В общем- не иначе, но я же указал в названии что это про wordpress. По аналогии с полем не работает

Comment: Просто нужно найти нужное поле